# "iPhone created a strong password for this website" popup appearing when tapping on a secure text field

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a secure area, but I am getting an error like this, what should I do?

[image: Screenshot of the popup]

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error, this is an iCloud Keychain alert that lets users generate passwords in secure text fields. This is a useful feature for those who don't want to choose a password themselves.

[More info about iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085)